# Troubleshooting digital picture frame backlight not working

Tags: backlight

I have one of those old digital picture frame ([TELEFUNKEN DPF 9322](https://manualsbrain.com/en/manuals/191684/)) and it stopped showing pictures. I took it apart and after some troubleshooting I found out that the issue is the backlight on the screen not getting enough power.
The backlight itself seems to be fine, if I put 7.5-8V from an external power supply on the backlight connector of the display, it shows fine.

So, I have been trying to figure out the issue on the main board, because it seems like it is not outputting the right voltage. If I measure the backlight connector on the main board, it is outputting ~7V (before doing anything on the board) and now it is outputting 5V, but I changed a MOSFET so maybe I made it worse, I don't know...

This is a picture of what I believe is the part of the backlight circuit on the main board, the white socket is where the display's backlight connects to:

[image]

Closer picture taken with the microscope:

[image]

Picture of the entire front of the board:

[image]

Picture of the entire back of the board:

[image]

The MOSFET I replaced is Q5, it had the marking `A2SHB` and [this is the replacement I got](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002918393287.html). I replaced it because, under the microscope, it looked like it could have been damaged.

The capacitors are not soldered on the picture because I replaced them also with new ones, and I had them out in the moment I took the picture.

I'm using this as a learning experience, I like to keep learning about electronic and how things work, so if I'm not able to fix it I'm not worried, but at least I would like to learn how this work and what could be happening.
So I would like to ask if someone has any advice on what could be happening, or what could I test to diagnose the issue.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want to understand it, you need a schematic. You probably won't find this schematic online, so you need to create your own. Carefully follow the traces and draw a schematic.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'm missing some context too. For example I don't understand how the voltage is boosted up to get to what's needed on the backlight of the display. Or if backlight circuits are a kind of standard (maybe they are in some parts?). That is why I decided to ask, to see if someone could give me some hints on what components to test for example.
Thanks!

Comment: The capacitor, inductor, transistor, diode capacitor sequence is a classic boost converter, which is a circuit that causes the inductor to pulse higher voltage and then capactures that voltage with a diode and capacitor.  Just looking at the picture it isn't obvious to me what causes the transistor to switch (the gate is maybe wired to something on the backside?) but that is the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the information @user1850479
I'm going to do some investigation about that boost converter config.
I've edited the question to add a picture of the whole board (front and back). There doesn't seem to be anything on the back of the board on that area.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lower cap (EC6) provides some intermediate input voltage (5V?). In the first state of the boost cycle, the MOSFET (Q5) shorts this voltage through the coil (330) to GND. So the coil gets energized. In the second state of the boost cycle, Q5 releases the short and the current flows through the diode D8 into the upper cap (EC9). (You can say that the coil "shoots" its energy through the diode into the output cap.)

There must be some resistor divider feedback path to the boost controller so it is able to find the correct duty cycle for the desired (high) output voltage.

That's how the boost converter magic works and I hope that you can repair it with this info.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to fix it and, what is more important, to understand a bit better how the voltage boosting works there.
I put a resistor on R89 (I don't have the schematics so I put 1KΩ) and now the backlight circuit is outputting ~15V.
What I believed happened is that I accidentally dragged R89 while replacing Q5 probably... because I did it without a microscope.